# не получается woocommerce в админке отображать на русском

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Поставил чистый wordpress русский, на него WooCommerce, а он английский язык выдаёт. Порылся в инете, везде советуют в Status > Tools нажать кнопочку "Force Translation Upgrade", но её там нет...
хотя в настройках System status написано

```
Language: ru_RU
```

П.С.: В файле wp-config.php прописал строку:

```
define('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В директории wp-content/languages/ нужно создать директорию woocommerce и в нее поместить файлы:

```
woocommerce-ru_RU.mo
woocommerce-ru_RU.po
```

П.С.: в директории wp-content/languages/ так же должны находится файлы ru_RU.mo и ru_RU.po,. Тогда при переключении языка в админке - плагин woocommerce  тоже сменит язык на язык админки

Answer (score 1):

Настройки языка задаются в профиле пользователя.

Если вся админка на русском, а только WC на англ - значит нет лангпака (нет файлов, нет прав и тп.).

> В файле wp-config.php прописал строку:

Это лишнее

Comment: что Вы имеете в виду под лангпаками?
я поставил плагин  
Saphali Woocommerce Russian, но это тоже не помогло...(права стоят везде 777, т.к. это учебный проект)

Comment: Лангпак - языковой пакет. Файлы *ru_RU.mo  и *ru_RU.po в каталоге `/wp-content/languages/plugins/` (системный) или [под]каталоге плагина (локальный). В данном случае это файлы woocommerce-ru_RU.po woocommerce-ru_RU.mo в системном каталоге переводов плагинов. Важно! Регистр имеет значение.

Comment: Saphali не нужен

Comment: @KAGGDesign сафали может помочь в другом - корректное отображение рубля и кое-какие настройки. (Хотя рубль он... мягко говоря коряо показывает и я бы лучше делал [этим костылём](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b-2/#post-257592) )

Comment: @SeVlad saphali ru делали, когда были проблемы в WC  с рублём и переводом. Все это уже давно в прошлом. Ненужный плагин.

Comment: @KAGGDesign да я в курсе его истории. Но проблемы с отображением рубля в WC есть и по сей день. А сафали не только это "исправляет" (хотя и коряво, если глянуть в html), но и даёт весьма полезные возможности настройки ИМа. Поля там, и пр. Многим это нужно.

Comment: @SeVlad файлы ru_RU.mo & ru_RU.po присутствуют в указанной Вами папке, но НЕТ поля "Force Translation Upgrade" , чтобы изменить язык

Comment: У меня ничего подобного тоже [нет](https://i.imgur.com/sGWOc7F.jpg), WC и ВП всё на русском. проверяй права доступа, целостность файлов итд Можешь скачать лангпак отдельно и поместить как я выше писал: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/ru/default И внимательно прочитай сам ответ.