# Почему в плагине woocommerce (wordpress) файлы .po и .mo не все переводят?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему  в плагине  woocommerce (wordpress) файлы .po и .mo не все переводят?
строки 1 и 2 прописаны в файле woocommerce-ru_RU.po, но перевелась только строка 2, в то время, как строка 1 НЕ перевелась, хотя она прописана...

П.С.: таких строк, которые есть в файле .po, но не перевелись довольно-таки много...

Comment: Ты точно хочешь знать ПОЧЕМУ. или может КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ? И версии не мешает показывать.

Comment: Хотя я ж уже всё объяснял https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714631

Comment: @SeVlad, хочу знать ПОЧЕМУ! Не, админка woocommerce перевелась (до этого она НЕ переводилась совсем), но некоторые слова НЕ перевелись и это осталось ВНЕ моего понимания...

Comment: ОК. Есть много причин "почему", но телепатов нет, а гадание с наводящими вопросами не для SO. Основная причина "почему" есть в прошлом ответе.